# What is the difference between handle and thread?

Tags: .net, windows

I see in Windows Task Manager -> Performance tab under system block, I see Process, threads and handle statistics.

Can some body tell me what are handles(with technical information including development point of view)?

Comment: The handle count is the number of handles the process has open.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 25):

A thread is part of the process, running within its own execution space and there can be multiple threads in one process.
with the help of it os can do multiple tasks in parallel(depends upon the number of processors of the machine.

A handle is a generic OS term that can be a  ticket to an operating system object. Each handle is unique and identifies each object. A thread is an OS object and each one you create, you get back a handle for it.

Under Windows, the thread handle is different from the thread ID, in the same way that a file handle is different from a file name.

The thread handle is a token which allows you to do something with the thread (typically wait for it or kill it). Win32 has these tokens for lots of objects, and calls them HANDLE in general.

Comment: This makes me think one thread has one handle but I see large number of handles while fewer threads. How so?

Comment: I agree, this explanation above seems incomplete.  This is a much better explanation - Handles indicates handles the threads may have open https://superuser.com/questions/1065826/handles-vs-threads-vs-processes